# Multi Dimensional Array vs Jagged Array Length method

Tags: c#

Why does a `[,]` style array `Length` method vs a `[][]` jagged style array `Length` method differ in that in the jagged array the length method returns the size of the closest rank where as in the `[,]` style array the `Length` method returns the whole number of elements not only of the closest rank (hence the need to use the `GetLength()` method.)

Comment: @PatrickKostjens  I have read that but i don't understand the difference in the Length method specifically. i Mean why would the length method in jagged arrays differ in the result that the length method in the "normal" arrays. Is there any reason?

Comment: Because `Length` returns the number of elements in the array. In a multi-dimensional array, this is naturally the total number of elements, since you have 1 array containing n elements. A jagged array is actually and array of arrays, so `Length` returns the number of arrays

Comment: Because a `something[x]` contains x elements. It shouldn't make a difference whether `something` is `int`, `string` or `somethingElse[]`. A `something[x, y]` on the other hand, is one object that contains x*y elements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Jagged arrays (`[][]`) arrays where the element type is an array too `[]`, so basically is just a one-dimension array.

Multidimensional arrays (`[,]`) are arrays that have more than one dimension, but all elements are in the same array.

`Length` property from **MSDN**:

> Gets the total number of elements in all the dimensions of the Array.

According to this `Length` in jagged array this property returns the number of arrays it contains.

In multidimensional arrays this property returns all elements in it, that is the multiplication of all dimension sizes.

`GetLength(int)` from **MSDN**:

> Gets an integer that represents the number of elements in the specified dimension of the Array.

Using this method for jagged arrays, the only available dimension is `0`, that returns the same value as `Length` property.

In multidimensional arrays you can pass the zero-based index of the desired dimension. For example in `[,,]` available dimensions are `0`, `1` and `2`.